# Reading input integer in Java

Tags: java, input, int, java.util.scanner

When I run this program, it doesn't work. I can enter your name, my birth year, the current year but after I enter the current year it doesn't display my age. Could you tell me what's wrong in my code and explain me why ? It seems like I didn't understand how input works in Java.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner get_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name ");
        String name = get_input.nextLine();


        boolean is_int = false;
        int year_of_birth = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter your year of birth");
        while (!get_input.hasNextInt()) {

            System.out.println("Year invalid");
            System.out.println("Enter your year of birth");
            get_input.next();
        }
        year_of_birth = get_input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the current year");
        get_input.next();
        int current_year=get_input.nextInt();

        int age = current_year-year_of_birth;

        System.out.println(current_year);
        System.out.println(year_of_birth);
        System.out.println("Your name is " + name + " and you are " + age + " year old.");

        get_input.close();

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you remove the  get_input.next(); after printing the "Enter the current year" your problem should go away. I would also add error checking in that area because the user can enter an invalid year.

Comment: Thanks Albert. I made this only to learn how it works. I guess I didn't really understand what's the purpose of ".next();". Why isn't it necessary?

Comment: Finds the next token keyword from the scanner. Since that isn't happening the code blocks. Here is the library reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--.

Comment: Thanks. If you post your answer as an answer, I will validate it.

Comment: Just did that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the get_input.next(); after printing the "Enter the current year" your problem should go away. I would also add error checking in that area because the user can enter an invalid year.

Answer (score 0):

just eliminate line `get_input.next();` which is after you print `System.out.println("Enter the current year");` and the code should work.

Comment: :) actually copied your code to the editor and looked at it there, when there was no comment in this post. Do you think I should delete it?

Comment: No but from my point of vue you might as well have copied their message. If you tried to solve my problem, I appreciate it.

Comment: that way there would be a risk of the wrong answer and 'answer not useful vote' which degrades one's reputation. Why would anyone do that?